# Expect script seeing \r characters injected into data flow when run in crontab

Tags: linux, bash, shell, expect

I am using crontab to launch a bash script which executes an expect script.
The expect script's function is to login to another server using SSH and then perform different tasks, including logging into another server and performing tasks.
This works without issue today:

```
 script server          jump server          data server
+--------------+      +-------------+      +-------------+
| openSuSE12.3 |  ->  |   Sol 10    |  ->  |    Sol 10   |
| bash 4.2.53  +------+     ksh     +------+     ksh     |
| expect 5.4.5 |      |             |      |             |
+--------------+      +-------------+      +-------------+
```

I now have to migrate to a new RHEL data server, which has uncovered an issue.

```
 script server          jump server          data server
+--------------+      +-------------+      +-------------+
| openSuSE12.3 |  ->  |   Sol 10    |  ->  |  RHEL 6.8   |
| bash 4.2.53  +------+     ksh     +------+ bash 4.?.?? |
| expect 5.4.5 |      |             |      |             |
+--------------+      +-------------+      +-------------+
```

When I launch the bash script from the command line it works without issue.
When I launch the bash script in an env created based on the crontab env it works without issue.
When the crontab executes the expect script it is seeing \r characters injected into the data flow from the data server bash session, which is causing expect to fail to detect the expected output.

For example this:

```
[november@ab1c23 ~]$
```

Turns into this when run in crontab (as shown with expect debug enabled):

```
[nov\rvembe\rber@\r@ab1\r1c23\r3 ~]\r]$
```

For troubleshooting I have stripped the bash and expect scripts down to the basic functions of: login and logout of the first server, and changed the first server SHELL to bash, which has recreated the issue on the first server.
I have tested on two Linux script servers with the same result (Note: both are connecting to the same Unix server as this is required).

```
+--------------+      +-------------+
| openSuSE12.3 |  ->  |   Sol 10    |
| bash 4.2.53  +------+ bash 3.2.57 |
| expect 5.4.5 |      |             |
+--------------+      +-------------+

+--------------+      +-------------+
| ubuntu 16.04 |  ->  |   Sol 10    |
| bash 4.3.46  +------+ bash 3.2.57 |
| expect 5.4.5 |      |             |
+--------------+      +-------------+
```

**Bash script (TEST.sh):**

```
#!/bin/bash

/usr/bin/expect -d -f /home/foxtrot/test_bash_login.exp >> /home/foxtrot/LOGIN_TEST_RUNLOG.log

exit 0
```

**Expect script (test_bash_login.exp):**

```
#!/usr/bin/expect --

spawn /usr/bin/ssh november@ab1c23
expect {
  timeout {send_user "Exp timeout during login\n" ; exit}
  "ab1c23 ~]$ "
}

send "exit\r"
expect {
  timeout {send_user "Exp timeout during exit_to_prompt\n" ; exit}
  "exit"
}

exit 0
```

**CRONTAB on script server:**

```
* * * * * /home/foxtrot/TEST.sh 2>> /home/foxtrot/LOGIN_TEST_CRONLOG.log &
```

As suggested in other threads I captured the crontab environment using this line in crontab:

```
* * * * * env > ~/cronenv
```

Then I executed the following command to enter the crontab env:

```
env - `cat ~/cronenv` /bin/sh
```

I then ran the bash script and there were no issues

**Manual script run using crontab environment**

```
sh-4.2$ env
SHELL=/bin/sh
USER=foxtrot
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin
PWD=/home/foxtrot
HOME=/home/foxtrot
SHLVL=2
LOGNAME=foxtrot
_=/usr/bin/env

expect version 5.45
argv[0] = /usr/bin/expect  argv[1] = -d  argv[2] = -f  argv[3] = /home/foxtrot/test_bash_login.exp
set argc 0
set argv0 "/home/foxtrot/test_bash_login.exp"
set argv ""
executing commands from command file /home/foxtrot/test_bash_login.exp
parent: waiting for sync byte
parent: telling child to go ahead
parent: now unsynchronized from child
spawn: returns {11850}

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "ab1c23 ~]$ "? no

expect: does "Last login: Wed Jan 11 18:04:55 2017 from victor\r\r\nYou have mail.\r\n\r\n[november@ab1c23 ~]$ " (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "ab1c23 ~]$ "? yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) "ab1c23 ~]$ "
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp4"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) "Last login: Wed Jan 11 18:04:55 2017 from victor\r\r\nYou have mail.\r\n\r\n[november@ab1c23 ~]$ "
send: sending "exit\r" to { exp4 }

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "exit"? no

expect: does "exit\r\nexit\r\n" (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "exit"? yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) "exit"
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp4"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) "exit"
```

You'll notice above the expected string:

```
"ab1c23 ~]$ "
```

is seen in the session output:

```
"[november@ab1c23 ~]$ "
```

However when crontab runs the script there are \r characters injected multiple times into the prompt output causing a parsing failure.

**crontab execution**

```
expect version 5.45
argv[0] = /usr/bin/expect  argv[1] = -d  argv[2] = -f  argv[3] = /home/foxtrot/test_bash_login.exp
set argc 0
set argv0 "/home/foxtrot/test_bash_login.exp"
set argv ""
executing commands from command file /home/foxtrot/test_bash_login.exp
parent: waiting for sync byte
parent: telling child to go ahead
parent: now unsynchronized from child
spawn: returns {11633}

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp3) match glob pattern "ab1c23 ~]$ "? no

expect: does "Last login: Wed Jan 11 17:51:51 2017 from victor\r\r\nYou have mail.\r\n\r\n[nov\rvembe\rber@\r@ab1\r1c23\r3 ~]\r]$  \r" (spawn_id exp3) match glob pattern "ab1c23 ~]$ "? no
expect: timed out
```

Now you'll notice above the expected string:

```
"ab1c23 ~]$ "
```

is **not** seen in the session output because of the introduced \r strings:

```
"[nov\rvembe\rber@\r@ab1\r1c23\r3 ~]\r]$  \r"
```

Any \r injected at lines end, i.e changing \n to \r\n, is not a concern, i can adapt for that.  The odd behavior I am struggling with is the injection of the \r characters mid-line and in the prompt output.

For the prompt I could expect on a smaller portion of the prompt and avoid these injections, however it would not solve the issue overall as these \r characters are being injected throughout the session.  They are not isolated to the first login or just the prompt.  They infect the whole session at different times making anticipating expected output difficult to impossible.

They seemed random, however I feel their may be some trigger that causes them but I am unable to understand what that may be.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE:** I will add that it appears the injections are "consistent".  I've ran the script 10 times in a row and the same string is returned (see below).  The \r injections do not move around.

```
"[nov\rvembe\rber@\r@ab1\r1c23\r3 ~]\r]$  \r"
```

Comment: This is a well researched question! `++`

Comment: You have got the crontab environment and have used to add to the script launched from the command line, haven't you? But have you tried the opposite? I mean, have you compared the crontab environment to the environment your terminal session holds from which you launch the script by hand? Perhaps that could show you a clue.

Comment: I originally used the link below to bring in my normal environment into the crontab execution of the script:

http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27289/how-can-i-run-a-cron-command-with-existing-environmental-variables

This still had manual execution working with crontab failing.  Additionally, I believe by entering the same environment as crontab runs in I am removing any difference in the environments.  I will explore the differences a bit closer, but if I'm running both in the same environment then there should be nothing to compare.

Comment: Based on your investigation it seems to me the problem has nothing to do with the *data server*. But then it's confusing why it worked fine before you migrated the *data server* from `sol 10` to `rhel`. ???

Comment: I agree.  It seems more related with remote bash sessions.  The new data server is forcing me to bash, so the problem appears the same when I use bash on the jump server.

Comment: I don't know what's the problem but I think you can try `export TERM=vt100` in the bash script before `expect -f`. Not sure if `vt100` is available on sol-10. You can also try `xterm`, `dtterm`, `sun-color`, `ansi`, ...